# Redirect URI for Google SignIn for Android App

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to get an Flutter app to use Oauth2 to sign in to Google using the Flutter package "flutter_web_auth_2: ^2.1.5".

The call to this is the code below:

```
  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // App specific variables
    const googleClientId = 'MY CLIENT ID';
    const callbackUrlScheme = 'com.example.googlesignin3';

    // Construct the url
    final authUrl = Uri.https('accounts.google.com', '/o/oauth2/v2/auth', {
      'response_type': 'code',
      'client_id': googleClientId,
      'redirect_uri': '$callbackUrlScheme:/',
      'scope': 'email',
    });

    // Present the dialog to the user
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth2.authenticate(url: authUrl.toString(), callbackUrlScheme: callbackUrlScheme);

    // Extract code from resulting url
    final code = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];

    // Construct an Uri to Google's oauth2 endpoint
    final tokenUrl = Uri.https('www.googleapis.com', 'oauth2/v4/token');

    // Use this code to get an access token
    final response = await http.post(tokenUrl, body: {
      'client_id': googleClientId,
      'redirect_uri': '$callbackUrlScheme:/',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
    });

    // Get the access token from the response
    final accessToken = jsonDecode(response.body)['access_token'] as String;
    print(accessToken);
  }
```

The manifest file has:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth_2.CallbackActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.example.googlesignin3" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When this runs, it opens the browser on the phone, but just hangs. I imagine I need the right authorised URL in the google console? If I go there then I can put "com.example.googlesignin3:/" as it says this is invalid. From what I understand, I am supposed to set the URL scheme in backwards notation as in "com.example.googlesignin3".

I don't understand what I'm meant to put into the Google console. I can't find anything that explains it clearly. Please can someone help.